# Org-ref not communicating with Tex-live?

Tags: org-mode, latex, debugging

Org-ref cannot tell that I have `biblatex-caspervector` installed.

[image: bibstyle installed via Texlive but not detected.]

[image: Insert citations command still unavailable.]

Is this because of some packages that I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the command `kpsewhich biblatex-caspervector.bst` returned a non-zero status. That just means that command doesn't know where that bst file is, or that it doesn't exist. If your latex file builds fine, then it is not a problem. If it doesn't build and use that style, then it is not installed in a way that latex can find it.

Comment: How do I check and/or fix this?

Comment: You can run that command at the command line to check it. If it is an issue you have to look into Latex installation details for where to to put those style files. If your latex file builds fine though I would probably ignore it.

Comment: Where are these `.bst` files usually stored? I need to know the path where Texlive installed the file, presuming it exists.

Comment: @Kurt over [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/496582/165606) says that `biblatex` does not use `.bst` files. `kpsewhich` is a pathfinder?

Comment: yes, kpsewhich is used to find things in your latex paths. I don't use biblatex myself, so I am not too familiar with it. you should see the link to org-ref and biblatex in the link you listed above though.

Comment: I've found the path to `caspervector.bbx`: `kpsewhich caspervector.bbx
/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-caspervector/caspervector.bbx`